# SPLUNK: extract and rank values from single event

Tags: regex, extract, splunk

Hi I have a field which has repeated groups of "`<id>:<Flag>:<Rank>:<weight>:<quantity>`" separated by column.
Example, 2113:X:1:2.92400000:14100.00000:613:X:7:2.92800:96300.00000:1132:L:2:2.92750000:14300.00000

I want to extract the id corresponding to the highest weight. In the above example I would get 
Id  Weight
613 2.928

from my regex knowledge, I could only work with single repetition of the event. but not more than that

Comment: Regex isin't going to do math conditionals.

Comment: This is more of splunk query, than Regex. In splunk we could extract values into named fields and do the math on some stats on those fields

Comment: Then this regex `([^:]*):[^:]*:[^:]*:([^:]*):[^:]*` is for the repeating. Capture group 1 is the ID, group 2 is the weight. To be done in a global search.  Is there any line breaks?